# how do i make Zurb foundation @include single-transition to work with IE 9

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-9, sass, zurb-foundation

I have created a custom button using foundation. i used @include single-transition; to animate hover. But it doesn't work with IE9. How Do i make it to work with IE9.

```
.btn-t {
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: emCalc(16px);
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: rgba($primary-color, 0.9);
  @include single-transition;
}
.btn-t:hover {
  background: darken($primary-color, 20%);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transitions are not supported in IE9: http://caniuse.com/#search=transition

Here i duplicate the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8727496/901944) by @Barney:

> It is possible to detect supported CSS properties, provided you're
>   aware in advance of what browser vendor prefixes you need to sniff
>   for. I've written a gist for the mechanism:
>
> https://gist.github.com/1096784
>
> cssSandpaper is a JS library that aims to parse CSS and dynamically
>   implement polyfills for various CSS3 effects:
>
> http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/
>
> There is also a jQuery library that operates in reverse order, and
>   silently implements transitions where possible when you call
>   $.animate():
>
> https://github.com/louisremi/jquery.transition.js