# What i can use transition in IE 8?

Tags: html, css

I design a web page . I use transition in this page.
but it do not work at IE 8 . can you help me?

```
transition-property: height;
transition-duration: 2s;
-webkit-transition-property: height;
-webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
transition-property: width;
transition-duration: 2s;
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/css-transitions Not in IE8, not in IE9.

Comment: IE8 only supports CSS 2.1 (and not perfectly, even if Microsoft says it does)

Comment: Oh no, people who have disabled Windows Update won't be able to enjoy the beautiful web that was part of the advertisement campaign for IE9! Whatever shall we do? ... My answer would be to either tell them to update, or just not care ;)

Answer (score 3):

Transitions do not work in IE8 or below.

([Reference](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition))

You can use [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/) in future to see which features do (or don't) work with browsers.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 does not support CSS3 transitions.

You can find more informations on this question if you want to make transitions on IE8 : [CSS3 Transition Polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974648/css3-transition-polyfill)