# Making the Multi-level Push menu work in IE

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer-9

The new [Codrops multi-level push menu](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/13/multi-level-push-menu/comment-page-1/#comments) is awesome and is honestly exactly what I need for a project I have right now; the problem is that it doesn't work in Internet Explorer 9, which I have to support.

The animations (beyond the initial push effect of course) are all nice-to-haves, but not necessary for me; what I really need is the nested menus, because the menu structure I'm developing will turn out to be rather deep.

As it's for a Javascript application, that requirement is a nonissue. What really matters is getting it to work in Internet Explorer 9, which doesn't support Transforms; so how do I pull this off?

Comment: You can try polyfil, check  [this tipic][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344745/polyfill-shim-for-css-transitions-and-animations

Comment: If you ever managed to get this working it would be awesome if you were willing to share the code ;)

Comment: I did actually get a version of it working, but two caveats: one, for some reason on my Chrome (and no one else's) the framerate is stuttery at best; and two, because I was using it within a Knockout app context, I took advantage of a lot of Knockout-specific features to actually build it, which heavily limits the potential applications without heavy adaptation. I'm not really sure how useful sharing that would be honestly.

Comment: Any answer to the question : 
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620638/multi-level-push-menu-state-from-page-to-page

Comment: Codrops multi-level push menu which is not work in the Internet Explorer in Lumia Devices. Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed Multi-level push menu to work with IE8+.
Could be the following jQuery plugin can fit your needs too. It's inspired by [Codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/13/multi-level-push-menu/) MultiLevelPushMenu implementation, but not based on CSS 3D Transforms.

[jquery.multilevelpushmenu at GitHub](https://github.com/adgsm/multi-level-push-menu)

Comment: Like I said in my comment, I managed to put this together in an IE9+ compliant way using some application-specific Javascript; thanks for the link though, very cool plugin! I'll mark this as the accepted answer in case anyone else needs this.