# Multi-level push menu state from page to page

Tags: php, javascript, html, menu

I'm attempting to use a multi-level push menu I found here:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/08/13/multi-level-push-menu/

The source is available there as well. I've adapted the source to work MOSTLY the way I want. I have pieces in php includes so that there is minimal reloading of portions when I go from page to page.

The one part I can't get to stick is the actual menu on the left hand side. When I click on a link, the menu disappears/completely collapses. Does anyone know how I can adapt this so that the menu state is saved when navigating from page to page?

Thanks!

Comment: Creating a jsfiddle will help expedite getting an answer

Comment: Pls show your actual code, or better yet create a jsfiddle or other demo. This will greatly improve the odds of your question being answered.

Answer (score 0):

It's suggested on their blog to change 'this.open' to 'true' within the '_init' method.

```
_init : function() {
...
this.open = true;
```

However this didn't work for me!

Invoking '_openMenu()' method at initialization time, right after 'this._init()' will expand menu but could potentially bring problems with event listener for body click...

```
function mlPushMenu( el, trigger, options ) {
    this.el = el;
    this.trigger = trigger;
    this.options = extend( this.defaults, options );
    // support 3d transforms
    this.support = Modernizr.csstransforms3d;
    if( this.support ) {
        this._init();
        this._openMenu();  // added
    }
}
```

Second possibility:

If you want to "save" exact menu position, perhaps you could use following [jQuery multi-level push menu plug-in](https://github.com/adgsm/multi-level-push-menu), and then before leaving the page, to determine current menu state:

`var $activeMenu = $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'activemenu' );`

Thereafter you can post whatever data from it (e.g. 'id')

`var menuID = $activeMenu.attr( 'id' );`

to the next page and use it in there to find and expand the same menu level again using 'expand' method.

`$( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'expand', $( '#' + menuID ) );`