# How can i change the position of an image in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, image, animation, scroll

I have an image like this:

[image]

and i want to change the position in jquery on hover to make it look the the image is changing.

I dont want to use the .animate function to shift the image but, to basically have the image scroll to each frame.

right now i have a width set, and my overflow to hidden so you can only see one image at a time.

my HTML

```
 <ul class="icons">
                    <li id="trasklogo"><img src="img/icons/nav-se1aec3ccea.png" width="75" height="823" /></li>
                    <li><img src="img/icons/sprite_about.png" width="1050" height="70" /></li>
                    <li><img src="img/icons/sprite_genetics.png" width="1050" height="70" /></li>
                    <li><img src="img/icons/sprite_innovation.png" width="1050" height="70" /></li>
                    <li><img src="img/icons/sprite_media.png" width="1050" height="70" /></li>
                </ul>
```

my CSS

```
ul li, {
list-style: none;
}

li {
display: list-item;
text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
.menu .icons #trasklogo {
height: 87px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.container .menu .icons {
width: 75px;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: [Spritely](http://spritely.net/) is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish.

If you are trying to make this sprite an animation, take a look at [Spritely](http://spritely.net/). This javascript will automatically move the sprite to emulate keyframe animation. You simply supply a width and how quickly the sprite should move and it will do the rest.

If you are trying to slowly pan across the image and stop, your best bet *would* be to use animate on the background x position. I doubt this is your intention based on the sprite you've supplied and the fact that you requested not to use animate.

You could also emulate this animation with CSS using `@keyframes`. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLyrN/

Note: CSS animations are not cross-browser compatible without a [polyfill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344745/polyfill-shim-for-css-transitions-and-animations).

Comment: i guess i had the uses for the animate function wrong. Sorry English is not my native language but what you described sounds like what i intended to do. I want to pan across the image and stop on key frames to emulate animation when the user hovers over the list item.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create that effect in Javascript with JQuery.

```
setInterval(function() {
    // parse the current margin to an integer and substract the with of one frame
    var nr=parseInt($("#sw").css("margin-left")) - 70; 
    // reset margin to 0 if margin > last frame
    if(nr<=-1050) {
        nr=0;
    }
    // set the new margin
    $("#sw").css("margin-left", nr+"px");
}, 50);
```

CSS:

```
#wr {
    width:70px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wr">
    <img id="sw" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCX5s.png" />
</div>
```

Working example: **http://jsfiddle.net/U2MrB/**